# How do I check whether a windows program is running or not?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to check if a specific program is running (not a python file, but e.g. an executable) and I don't really have an idea how to do it.

I have tried using `Window.get_all_windows()` from dragonfly (see code sample below) but it returns a list of objects I can't really work with.

```
#Python 3.7

from dragonfly import Window as win

open_programs_list = win.get_all_windows()

print(open_programs_list)
```

I really much appreciate your time and help.